# Have a key perform two actions simultaneously in different programs

Tags: dcs-world

I'm looking to create *something* that enables me to fire my weapon in DCS Flight Simulator by pressing a joystick button, and at the same time the button is depressed start recording video in NVIDIA Shadowplay (using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>).

It then needs to stop the recording after 15 seconds have elapsed (in case I'm firing in bursts).

This is to try to simulate a gun camera in the WW2 style aircraft, but could apply to other games also.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: Can't you change the keyboard mapping in DCS, or in Shadowplay?

Comment: Hi Ollie, rereading your question it seems you need an automated script. As this has nothing to do with gaming (the game is just used as an example), I'm afraid it is off-topic here on Arqade. I can suggest trying [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). But be sure to have a look at [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) first, because I think that's exactly what you need.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about automating key mapping, and has, as such, nothing to do with gaming.